# flexibility polyfill with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, polyfills

As the title say, I'm trying to use [flexibility](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility) in my meteor app. So in my client folder, I have added the `flexibility.js` file and my main.html look like this:

```
<head>
 <title>FROG</title>
 <script src="https://*****.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="flexibility.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

But when I load the client on localhost I get (on the client console)

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
that says it refers to `flexibility.js` at the first line: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I don't get what's wrong, please help me :)